# Comments before head tag breaks javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I am writing additional javascript code that is being parsed by a PC client that runs in an instance of IE 7.

The original HTML code I am modifying does not have a doctype declaration and html meta tags. Also, the original HTML code has a multiline comment immediately after the opening HTML tag like this:

```
<html>
       <!-- 
              Some comments 
              Some more comments 
              Some more comments 
       -->
       <head>
       </head>

       <body>
       </body>
</html>
```

When I add a doctype declaration and meta tags to make the code look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
       <!-- 
              Some comments 
              Some more comments 
              Some more comments 
       -->
       <head>
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
       </head>

       <body>
       </body>
</html>
```

I start to get weird errors like **Object doesn't support property or method 'query Selector'** when I try DOM manipulation.
I understand having comments immediately after the opening html tag may be invalid HTML but I cannot relocate the comments as that causes other parts of the PC client to fail. I have no access to the source code of the PC client and I think it was written in C#.

What can I do?

Comment: `of IE 7` - please consider using a more modern browser if that browser is exposed outside of an internal network as that version (or any IE version) is no longer supported and may have security issues now or in the future and likely will not work on a growing number of sites as time progresses.

Comment: Maybe the site only worked in IE7 because the absence of DOCTYPE triggered the quirks mode? See the [wikipedia page about quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), note that as answers state, if you can't make your client upgrade the browser, you'll need to use only JS functions / CSS supported by the browser

Comment: From Microsoft: **"Support for Internet Explorer ended on June 15, 2022. Internet Explorer 11 has been permanently disabled through a Microsoft Edge update on certain versions of Windows 10.

If any site you visit needs Internet Explorer 11, you can reload it with Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge."**  Good luck on your quest as it will likely experience more challenges in the future.  AS for your question: replace the pc client with something else.

Comment: IE, most js of it's function not running well, if IE.7 is the prefer browser, I recommend you to use a ```polyfill```. It means *querySelector* couldn't use as  it run only in latest browser and you use a *jQuery* which was it support in IE. *find and filter* also is not running in IE, *indexOf* is you could replace.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 7 is **exceptionally** ancient. It does not support [querySelector](https://caniuse.com/queryselector).